# How to get the base directory in visual studio code snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am trying to get the file current directory in a snippet for visual studio code.

[VSCode has a variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables): `TM_DIRECTORY`, which is the **fullpath**.

eg:

```
{folder: "$TM_DIRECTORY"}
```

would be replaced by

```
{folder: "/Volumes/my-project-path/ParentFolder/MyFolder"}
```

But I want only `MyFolder`.

Normally, we can use a [transform as indicated in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms). Sublime Text works in the same way. But for as much as I try, the snippet simply outputs the whole regex.

Could someone answer with the magical variable/transform? :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ok, finally found it.

`${TM_DIRECTORY/^.+\\/(.*)$/$1/}` gives the base directory.

The part I didn't get was the "double escape" of the directory separator `/` -> `\\/`.

Comment: How to escape \Volumes\my-project-path\ParentFolder\MyFolder  ?

Comment: Nevermind found it too: `${TM_DIRECTORY/^.+\\\\(.*)$/$1/}`

Comment: I dont get how vscode snippets are working but definitely it differ from regex101. I tried this `${TM_DIRECTORY/(\\w+)$/$1/}` and it just doesnt work, thought I expected it to take last word before end of string as it does here https://regex101.com/r/kc7oNF/1

Answer (score 12):

This supports Windows & Unix:

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/^.+[\\/\\\\]+(.*)$/$1/}
```

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to add that in Windows the code above will print the entire directory.

You need to add a quadruple backslash vs the forward-slash:

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/^.+\\\\(.*)$/$1/}
```

Comment: What is this language called? I'd like to understand it to use it on my own.

Comment: @sayandcode I think it's just plain JavaScript. It's just escaping the strings due to parsing.

Comment: Plain JS? I tried using this snippet in Neovim, and its not working at all. I assumed it was some kind of regex. What do you mean by plain JS?

Comment: @sayandcode are you using Linux/WSL or Windows? That code works only for Windows.

Comment: @sayandcode I'm sorry, it's not plain JavaScript. VSCode follows the TextMate syntax  https://macromates.com/manual/en/snippets. You can learn more about it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Big help! Thanks! I'm on linux btw, is there some keyword I should look out for?