# Snippet: transorm TM_DIRECTORY base dir from snake_case to PascalCase

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to get "base directory" from TM_DIRECTORY variable (which gives full path) to be transformed to PascalCase (which is in snake_case).

So, for `/this/is/path/to/base_dir`, I want to get `BaseDir`

This is what I've got so far:

`${TM_DIRECTORY/(^.+\\/(.*)$)/${2:/capitalize}/g}` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366014/how-to-get-the-base-directory-in-visual-studio-code-snippet)

which gives me:

`Base_dir` for `/this/is/path/to/base_dir`

I feel like I have to somehow incorporate `${TM_DIRECTORY/((^[a-z])|_([a-z]))/${2:/upcase}${3:/upcase}/g}` but don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
  "${TM_DIRECTORY/(^.+\\/(.*)$)/${2:/pascalcase}/}",
```

the `pascalcase` option is unfortunately not documented.

If that option wasn't available I would suggest this:

```
  "${TM_DIRECTORY/.*\\/(.*)_(.*)$/${1:/capitalize}${2:/capitalize}/}",
```

the idea being to get the last directory in two capture groups, capitalize each and ignore the underscore separator (i.e., it doesn't appear in the transform part).

To generalize that, if you had other name separators in your directory name besides the underscore you could use this `[_-]` in that middle part - just include other possible separators.

Comment: `"${TM_DIRECTORY/(^.+\\/(.*)$)/${2:/pascalcase}/}"`, FTW! Thank you very much!